# How to test an embedder for face Recognition

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, dlib

Im trying to see the output after embedding an image. I tried using an opencv image function and ask to print the result, but it is not working. Any suggestions on how to test embedding using dlib?

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Get the position of each image in the embedding space.

Step2: Visualize it. May by the dimension is higher than 2D/3D you can use some methods like t-SNE to do the visualization.

[image]

Comment: can you demonstrate with python code sample your idea